# Is the DataContext part of Model in MVC or a part of Controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, datacontext, separation-of-concerns

working on asp.net MVC from quite some time now
today stuck on a theoretical problem
going through some sample code on MSDN
I read something like this

```
public class SomeController()
{
 public ActionResult SomeAction(SomeModel model)
 {
   var dataContext = new SomeDataContext();
   //basic CRUD operations on data context
   //
 }
}
```

here the database obviously is being accessed through the controller and by theory is incorrect
is there something wrong with this example or my definition of what a model and what a controller is needs to be refreshed
UPDATE:-
or there is a possibility that every where on MSDN `Models` and `ViewModels` are considered equal

Comment: Based on description, I would say that `ViewModel` is actually as properly implemented Model2-MVC `View`. And, what currently is called `View`, is actually just a dumb template.

Comment: If you perform interaction with storage using `DataContext` it is definitely part of **model layer**, since presentation layer should not be even aware of storage.

Comment: @tereško MVC is all part of the presentation layer. It's a GUI pattern and has nothing to do with the layers of an application.

Comment: @DennisTraub, the core principle of MVC is the separation of presentation and domain business logic. Please, go and educate: http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html

Comment: @tereško now what's the headline of the article you just linked? **GUI Architectures**. How does that contradict what I'm saying? Please, go and educate yourself.

Comment: @DennisTraub, please, read the small letters too ..

Comment: @tereško Nevermind, why would I argue with you. You just proved my point with the pattern description you posted, but still you're right, I'm wrong. Have a nice day :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### intro

MVC design pattern is quite old. It was [originally defined](http://www.itu.dk/courses/VOP/E2005/VOP2005E/8_mvc_krasner_and_pope.pdf) for Smalltalk-80 applications, when "web" was two guys sending ping between universities. Since then it has [evolved](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html) quite a lot.

The core principle behind MVC design pattern is [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). The pattern separates presentation from business logic. Presentation layer contains mostly views, controller, templates, viewmodels and presenters (depending on which flavor of MVC-inspired patterns you use), while business logic is ends in the model layer.

The model layer, while not strictly defines in the pattern, in ASP.NET MVC consists of services and all the structures that are used by service (including the Model Objects, better known as [domain objects](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DomainObject)).

#### regarding the question

It is quite common to see `DataContext` uses in controllers, when you are looking for basic MVC tutorials. MVC architecture is meant of large scale applications, and in a *Hello-World* example a fully realized MVC architecture would look like just bloat.

The examples sacrifice code separation for sake of simplicity. The interaction with `DataContext` is basically storage logic, which is one of tasks that model layer handles. When used in controller, it means that your model layer has begun leaking in the presentation layer, and you end up with *"Fat controller, skinny model"* problem.

In a real world application the `DataContext` would be part of structure that deal with persistence within model layer. Probably as part of [data mappers](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html), if you opt to write them manually.

#### regarding "update"

The model (I suppose in this case you meant Domain/Model object) is from completely different application layer then ViewModel.

As the name implies, in MVVM pattern the ViewModels replace the Controllers. ViewModel acquired data from model layer, and then transforms it in such a way that is usable for View.

This pattern is best used (if you are really using MVVM) in situation when you do not have full control over behavior over Views or/and Model layer. For example: if you were hired to build an alternative frontend for SAP or when the view is actually some form of hardware device, which expects specific type of input.

Comment: That's a great answer, it should be upvoted more often

Comment: @tereško MVC nicely explained, are you sure MVC has layers, model 'element' would be better IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

**MVC** is a GUI pattern, just like **MVP** or **MVVM**, it has nothing to do with data access and persistence. It's true that many simple CRUD applications are not much more that MVC and an underlying database, but in more complex applications MVC would be part of the presentation layer.

The `DataContext` as an O/RM belongs to the infrastructure layer, not the GUI. In MVC the **Model** can be understood as **ViewModel**, yes.

Nevertheless the controller can use the DataContext or any other means to retrieve this model from the underlying data store.

Comment: @tereško Oh, good to know. You must be the expert. Thanks for telling me.

Comment: Data access and persistence should always be part of model layer. Presentation layer deals with user input and generation of UI. Inv MVVM the ViewModel is a controller-level structure, that takes data from model layer and shapes it so that View can use it. DataContext as storage related structure, which has no place in presentation layer.

Comment: @tereško you already proved my point in the comments to the original question. No need to take it any further over here. Have a nice day :-)

Comment: @DennisTraub - then Asp.net MVC isn't really MVC because it clearly defines ways and methods to do CRUD operation on data.

Comment: @ParvSharma I would agree on ASP.Net MVC being not the ideal implementation of MVC, yes. It allows (or even encourages) intermingling unrelated concerns, like storage and retrieval on one hand and presentation on the other hand. But as I said, in simple CRUD apps you don't really need a business layer and can just hook up your MVC client to an active record or O/RM based infrastructure (which is what ASP.Net MVC as well as Raisl and other frameworks do by default).

Comment: @DennisTraub only thing that was proven was that you, instead of reading articles, just read the title and assume that you know what it means.

Comment: @tereško don't worry, I know Martin Fowler's work quite well. But you can't just leave it, or can you?

Comment: @teresko Unfortunately, you are incorrect. MVC is a pure Web architecture. The notion you describe about the presentation layer and the "model" layer (I think you mean Business Logic/Core layer) is actually the Three-Tier architecture, nothing to do with MVC (see MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms685068(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @mattytommo , you seem to confuse pattern with framework. MVC was never made for web. Which is actually part of the problem.

Comment: @DennisTraub Is tereško an expert? Dunno about that, but he does have silver MVC badge . . .

Comment: @mattytommo I've got to back teresko's last statement, MVC is from back in the 70s. It originally didn't have anything to do with the web at all.

Comment: @LeviMorrison he probably is an expert, still I disagree with him, which is perfectly fine. There's nothing set in stone and different opinions make our chosen profession the interesting one it is. On the other hand a silver badge doesn't say too much about your real expertise. I have a few and still learn something new every day. To be able to answer technical details when using a pattern doesn't necessarily mean you're grasping the architectural idea that lies behind.

Comment: @tereško Apologies, I was referring to ASP.NET MVC, **not MVC as a whole**

Comment: @LeviMorrison Whilst he may be an expert in MVC, it seems he has very few upvotes in the ASP.NET MVC area :)

Answer (score 0):

The Models are typically the data classes (representing the database tables). The View Models are typically referred to as classes that have been created in order to use them in the view for **presentation** purposes.

You wouldn't be able to use the `DataContext` on a View Model in the above case, but **you can use it perfectly fine with the above mentioned Model classes (also called DTO classes)**.

Comment: you mean to say SomeController is a DTO Class?

Comment: No, say for example you had a `Customer` table in your database, you'd have a `Customer` class in your application, that'd be a DTO (Data type object) class :)

Comment: yes that's what MSDN says using the DataContext through the Model Classes but here im initializing the dataContext in my controller isn't that a problem?

Comment: @ParvSharma it's fine to initialise it in the controller, it might be saying initialise it in the model to keep the controller as clean as possible (the good practice of thin controller and fat model).